awk print all columns with matching substring
I want to print columns that partially match a string (Phytophthora). The file is comma delimited. I prefer to use awk but all options are welcome :)
This is the first ten lines of my file:
head file
index,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_plurivora,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;g__Pythium;s__Pythium_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_psychrophila,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Saprolegniales;f__Saprolegniaceae;g__unidentified;s__Saprolegniaceae_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;g__Pythium;s__Pythium_grandisporangium,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytopythium;s__Phytopythium_citrinum,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Saprolegniales;f__Saprolegniaceae;g__Leptolegnia;s__Leptolegnia_sp,k__Viridiplantae;p__Anthophyta;c__Eudicotyledonae;o__Fagales;f__Fagaceae;g__Fagus;__,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;g__Globisporangium;s__Globisporangium_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;__,Unassigned;__;__;__;__;__;__,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Saprolegniales;f__Saprolegniaceae;g__Aphanomyces;s__Aphanomyces_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Saprolegniales;f__Saprolegniaceae;g__Pythiopsis;s__Pythiopsis_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Saprolegniales;f__Saprolegniaceae;g__Saprolegnia;s__Saprolegnia_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__unidentified;g__unidentified;s__Pythiales_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;g__Globisporangium;s__Globisporangium_heterothallicum,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;g__Globisporangium;__,k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Pleosporales;f__Pleosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Cheiromyces;s__Cheiromyces_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporaceae;g__Peronospora;s__Peronospora_chrysosplenii,k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Sordariomycetes;o__Hypocreales;f__Hypocreaceae;g__Trichoderma;__,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporaceae;g__Hyaloperonospora;s__Hyaloperonospora_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_obscura,k__Stramenopila;p__Ochrophyta;c__unidentified;o__unidentified;f__unidentified;g__unidentified;s__Ochrophyta_sp,k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Orbiliomycetes;o__Orbiliales;f__Orbiliaceae;__;__,k__Stramenopila;__;__;__;__;__;__,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Saprolegniales;f__Saprolegniaceae;__;__,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;g__Globisporangium;s__Globisporangium_rostratifingens,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;__;__,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_castanetorum,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_aleatoria,k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Orbiliomycetes;o__Orbiliales;f__Orbiliaceae;g__Dactylella;s__Dactylella_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;g__unidentified;s__Pythiaceae_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_vulcanica,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_europaea,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytopythium;s__Phytopythium_boreale,k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Pleosporales;f__Dictyosporiaceae;g__Dictyosporium;s__Dictyosporium_wuyiense,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__unidentified;f__unidentified;g__unidentified;s__Oomycetes_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;__;__;__;__,k__Stramenopila;p__unidentified;c__unidentified;o__unidentified;f__unidentified;g__unidentified;s__Stramenopila_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;g__Pythium;s__Pythium_chondricola,k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Pleosporales;f__Dictyosporiaceae;g__Digitodesmium;s__Digitodesmium_intermedium,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Saprolegniales;f__Saprolegniaceae;g__Aplanopsis;s__Aplanopsis_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;g__Pythium;__,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_crassamura,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;g__Pythium;s__Pythium_caudatum,k__Alveolata;p__Dinophyta;c__unidentified;o__unidentified;f__unidentified;g__unidentified;s__Dinophyta_sp,k__Viridiplantae;p__Anthophyta;c__Eudicotyledonae;o__Fagales;f__Fagaceae;g__Fagus;s__Fagus_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;g__Pythium;s__Pythium_graminicola,k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Pleosporales;f__Dictyosporiaceae;g__Pseudodictyosporium;s__Pseudodictyosporium_indicum,k__Amoebozoa;p__Variosea;c__unidentified;o__unidentified;f__unidentified;g__unidentified;s__Variosea_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporaceae;g__Peronospora;s__Peronospora_arvensis,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Oomycetes_ord_Incertae_sedis;f__Lagenaceae;g__Lagena;s__Lagena_sp,k__Viridiplantae;p__Anthophyta;c__Eudicotyledonae;o__Fagales;f__Fagaceae;g__Fagus;s__Fagus_sylvatica,k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Orbiliomycetes;o__Orbiliales;f__Orbiliaceae;g__Orbilia;s__Orbilia_auricolor,k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Pleosporales;f__Cucurbitariaceae;g__Neocucurbitaria;s__Neocucurbitaria_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;f__Pythiaceae;g__Globisporangium;s__Globisporangium_parvum,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Pythiales;__;__;__,k__Fungi;p__Mucoromycota;c__Umbelopsidomycetes;o__Umbelopsidales;f__Umbelopsidaceae;g__Umbelopsis;s__Umbelopsis_vinacea,absolute-filepath
11,0.0,34032.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,99.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,6742.0,0.0,3261.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,5793.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,608.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,11.reads.fastq.gz
12,2236.0,54019.0,0.0,0.0,8680.0,103.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1345.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1283.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1071.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1606.0,0.0,478.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,456.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,99.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,464.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,12.reads.fastq.gz
13,0.0,73152.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,131.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,13.reads.fastq.gz
14,0.0,23345.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,24.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,50.0,0.0,0.0,1468.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,5041.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,98.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,707.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,81.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,14.reads.fastq.gz
15,0.0,42605.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3590.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,12066.0,0.0,1729.0,12188.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,201.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1696.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,15.reads.fastq.gz
16,0.0,57495.0,0.0,0.0,2581.0,0.0,0.0,23.0,860.0,0.0,0.0,574.0,218.0,523.0,346.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3402.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,977.0,0.0,0.0,7.0,385.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,16.reads.fastq.gz
17,0.0,24558.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1807.0,0.0,0.0,68.0,145.0,0.0,9700.0,7040.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,5548.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,166.0,1292.0,0.0,2598.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,678.0,1563.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,157.0,0.0,0.0,33.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,295.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,165.0,0.0,17.reads.fastq.gz
18,0.0,55229.0,16003.0,0.0,10674.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,11626.0,485.0,0.0,0.0,841.0,0.0,0.0,20.0,84.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,779.0,905.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,168.0,0.0,24.0,120.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,588.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,101.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.reads.fastq.gz
1,98039.0,268.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2495.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.reads.fastq.gz

This is what I would like to see
k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_plurivora,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_sp
0.0,0.0
2236.0,0.0
0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0
0.0,16003.0

I can print the last match, but I can't get all matches printed:
awk -F',' -v word="Phytophthora" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if ($i ~ word) c=i } } c{print $c}' file

k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_crassamura
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
1567.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0

I also tried to store the matching columns as a variable and then add them into a second awk command:
variable=$(awk -F ','  '/Phytophthora/ { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ "Phytophthora") print "$"i }' file |
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } { print }')

awk -v var=$variable '{print var}'
$2 $4 $5 $12 $24 $31 $32 $35 $36 $46 
$2 $4 $5 $12 $24 $31 $32 $35 $36 $46 
$2 $4 $5 $12 $24 $31 $32 $35 $36 $46 
$2 $4 $5 $12 $24 $31 $32 $35 $36 $46 
$2 $4 $5 $12 $24 $31 $32 $35 $36 $46 


The search string (Phytophthora) matches 10 columns but in your desired output you want just 2. Is that correct?

consider reviewing minimal reproducible example, with an emphasis on minimal; you should be able to demonstrate the issue with 5-7 columns (as opposed to the current 61) which in turn may help alleviate some of the confusion with the current data sets

Since you may have more than one column with a match you need to modify the NF==1 processing to keep track of the column numbers (eg, via an array).
One idea:
awk -v word="Phytophthora" '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
            if ($i ~ word) 
               col_list[++c]=i 
      } 
      { for (i=1; i<=c; i++)
            printf "%s%s", $(col_list[i]), (i<c ? OFS : ORS)
      }
' file

This generates:
k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_plurivora,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_psychrophila,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;__,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_obscura,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_castanetorum,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_aleatoria,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_vulcanica,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_europaea,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_crassamura
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2236.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1071.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,5041.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2598.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,16003.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,905.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
98039.0,0.0,0.0,2495.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0

NOTES:

this code finds 10 columns with headers that contain the string Phytophthora
this does not match OP's expected output of 2 columns
however, OP's last set of awk|awk code shows that there are 10 columns with headers that contain the string Phytophthora
at this point I have to assume OP's expected output (2 columns) is incorrect and should really consist of 10 columns


i think col_list[ ] might function more effectively if you set it up like a singly linked list, starting with some arbitrary root index, and the array cell value is the next index (and thus, next column/field), plus setting the tail index with value of zero. Since at first row col_list[ ] is already created monotonically ascending, so this "singly-linked list" basically provides a pre-sorted iterator that works like idx = col_list[root_idx]; do { print $idx } while (idx = col_list[idx]) }'

The bonus being such a setup is even cleaner than a standard singly linked list, because you no longer need to access idx->next to locate the next item - every cell value coming out is already the the value of idx->next. One of my use cases for this structure is setting up a small primes tables, but unlike sequential integer indices, using the primes themselves as the indices mean one could literally begin iterating the primes starting at 367, for instance, without requiring a binary search or linear table scan to locate index of 367.

Sure one could make it half the weight by eliminating the cell values themselves and simply have sparse indices. But that would make it dependent on awks with sorting mechanisms, like gawk. The for ( idx in arr ) construct also makes it challenging if one desires to commence iteration at some random point along the way instead of always from the head or from the tail.

But I have yet to arrive upon a satisfactory approach to enhance this construct into a doubly-linked list (DLL) without doubling the array size. If one were only using gawk the DLL could just be made by having the indices themselves be the ascending list and the cell values be the descending list, so iterating upwards uses the for (idx in arr) { } loop construct, while iterating downwards would use do { } while (idx = arr[idx]) instead. It's very unideal to use 2 very different looping designs to handle 2 sides of the same coin. It's the best lemonade I could make out of lemons.

ps : the single single equal sign inside the do-while loop :::: do { } while (idx = arr[idx]) ::: isn't a typo for equality comparison - it's an intentional assignment - obtaining the cell value of curr. index, which, by design, is alrdy the next index needed. The loop also naturally terminates exactly at the tail, since the last array cell contains a zero value, and thus finally failing the loop continuation criteria, thus bypassing the need to even possess knowledge of # of elements in the array. The only extra annoyance is requiring a mechanism to store the root index.

The upside of this mechanism, compared to any existing iterator mechanism in just about any other language, is that indices along the same list have no requirement of being type compatible with each other whatsoever. I could literally have an emoji as a root index, the full binary data  of an mp3 file as next index, a Mersenne prime afterwards, and have last index being  the full JPEG binary file of trending meme.

This collection normally has no way of "iterating" in a sorted order other than 1, 2, 3, 4, but this singly-linked list mechanism enables that. Granted, one shouldn't be creating 4 MB indices in the first place - it's just an illustration of what surreal possibilities are possible at the extremes. You also avoid having to apply hash functions against binary indices ahead of time, and that all awks, regardless of locale setting, fully preserves the binary integrity of those indices. You could literally "print" out that MP3 index and have it be playable.

For an awk, markp-fuso has a great solution. That works with the example.
If you want to use a CSV parser (if your text has quotes or you want to easily generate some other data format) you can use Ruby:
ruby -r CSV -e 'AoA=CSV.parse($<.read)
idx=AoA[0].each.with_index.select{|fld, i| fld=~/Phytophthora/ }.map(&:last)
puts CSV.generate{|csv| 
        AoA.map{|row|
            csv<<row.select.with_index{|col, i| col if idx.include? i } 
        }
    }
' file.csv

Prints:
k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_plurivora,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_sp,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_psychrophila,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;__,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_obscura,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_castanetorum,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_aleatoria,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_vulcanica,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_europaea,k__Stramenopila;p__Oomycota;c__Oomycetes;o__Peronosporales;f__Peronosporales_fam_Incertae_sedis;g__Phytophthora;s__Phytophthora_crassamura
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2236.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1071.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,5041.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2598.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,16003.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,905.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
98039.0,0.0,0.0,2495.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0


Also, trivially with mlr:
$ mlr --csv cut -r -f 'Phytophthora' file.csv
# same output...


Using datamash and its transpose function:
datamash -t, transpose <file | grep Phytophthora | datamash -t, transpose

Possibly not the most efficient, but likely easier to understand.
Indeed, it only transforms the data to be able to filter the keyword (using grep) and transforms back the filtered data.

If partially match a string means contains then prefer index to a matching operator like ~. It works even if your string contains regex special characters (., *...) Example :
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v w='Phytophthora' '
  NR == 1 {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if(index($i, w)) {x[++n]=i}}
  {for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf("%s%s", $(x[i]), i==n ? "\n" : OFS)}' file

Note: we ignore your expected output because it does not match your specifications.
